# When an Angular 2 component has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angular

I cannot seem to find a hook by which I can know that a component that is made up of other child components has completely finished loading including data-binding and everything. For example take the following template for `ParentComponent`:

```
<div>
    <child-one>
        {{textOne}}
    </child-one>
    <child-two>
        {{textTwo}}
    </child-two>
</div>
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `ngAfterViewInit() {}` was called or if content is passed (`<ng-content>`), after `ngAfterContentInit()` was called.

---

- `ngAfterViewInit()` is called after the view initialization is completed. The component is fully loaded and initialized at this state.
- If also children passed to the component should be fully loaded then use `ngAfterContentInit()` instead.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: I had a typo, maybe this caused the confustion. `ngAfterViewInit()` is called after the view initialization is completed. The component is fully loaded and initialized at this state. If also children passed to the component should be fully loaded then use `ngAfterContentInit()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's wrong! ngAfterViewInit is fired when the view is being initialized...
Put a breakpoint into it and you will see. 
A hook to know when the view is actually fully loaded is really missing for Angular 2!
But as a workaround you could try something like that:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('View is being initialized');
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight);

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('View is fully loaded');
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Dimitri's answer, I've found that even after ngAfterViewInit is called, some elements were still not completely loaded, in my case I was after the scrollHeight of an element.

Using Ionic's `platform.ready()` and some timeout-testing, I noticed content finally being instantiated after about 60ms, so I increased it to 250ms just provide some wiggle-room. It's really not ideal but it's the last lifecycle hook to perform checks... but maybe it'll help someone?

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        /* still returns 0 here */
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight);

        setTimeout(() => {
            /* returns x here */
            console.log(this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight);
        }, 250);
    });
}
```

I know not everyone'll be using Ionic to have the `Platform` class available, it was only relevant to my use case as I was using ion-icons. But I left it in, in case it helps another Ionic user or something...

Answer (score 1):

Question being asked for Angular2... **but these hooks are still in action on 1st Jan 2024**.

`ngAfterViewInit` is the one mostly heared about, but if you are looking for a hook that register the event of all the templates getting finally rendered then `ngAfterViewChecked` is something you are looking for.

There are couple of more hooks including `ngAfterContentInit` and `ngAfterContentChecked` which can be explored here https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.

Hope this helps, cheers!